# Stepping into RFE and getting 'DataFrame object is not callable" error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, rfe

I'm trying to use RFE for the first time and banging my head against a "DataFrame object is not callable" error.

Here is my code

```
X, y = df5(n_samples=875, n_features=10, random_state=0)
estimator = SVR(kernel="linear")
selector = RFE(LinearRegression, step=1, cv=5)
selector = selector.fit(X, y)
df5([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)

selector.ranking_
df5([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 4, 3, 2, 5])
```

I'm looking at a dataset with 49 Features and the output I'm looking for is which of these features should be kept and which kicked out.

Bonus points if anyone can help me figure out how to get this into an RFECV!

Comment: What do you want by doing `df5([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 4, 3, 2, 5])`?

Comment: I don't remember where those numbers came from. Probably looking at someone else's code. Ultimately what I want is the features that I should be using for my model.

Comment: Do you want columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want select columns first figure out the information about your dataframe then select required features.

```
# the next 2 lines is to initialize DataFrame object (just for the example)
>>> from pandas import DataFrame
>>> df = DataFrame.from_dict({'one': range(10), 'two': range(10, 0, -1), 'three': [3 for x in range(10)]})

# now figure out what columns you df has:
>>> df.head()
   one  three  two
0    0      3   10
1    1      3    9
2    2      3    8
3    3      3    7
4    4      3    6
5    5      3    5
6    6      3    4
7    7      3    3
8    8      3    2
9    9      3    1

# Now you can slice specific columns (features in your case):
>>> df[['one', 'two']]
   one  two
0    0   10
1    1    9
2    2    8
3    3    7
4    4    6
5    5    5
6    6    4
7    7    3
8    8    2
9    9    1
```

Are your feature names numerical? I'm not sure. Check it.

Comment: I appreciate your help with this. It was clearly beyond my capabilities and I ended up going in another direction but I really do appreciate your help.

Comment: no, but I'm no longer searching for an answer myself. When I went to delete I was counseled against it so I just left it up. Should I kill it? To answer your question, though, the feature names are all strings.

Comment: You know what, I take that back. While the need is gone I'd still love to try to  do what I had hoped to, so if you can help that'd be great.

Comment: @ajbentley But if you can't clarify how did you get the numbers it's difficult to help. As minimum the repeating `1` looks strange.